# I've set my Facebook "Fan Page" to forward users to my company's website instead of the FB page. How can I reverse this?

Tags: facebook

A few months ago, I set my company's Facebook page to forward users directly to my company's website (instead of taking them to the usual fan page on Facebook).

I've realized that this isn't an advantage for me (I miss out on many of the social features of having a proper "fan page"), and I'd like to remove the auto-forward... but there doesn't seem to be a "forward to" setting that I can revert.

Am I just missing it in the Page Admin section, or was the act of assigning a "forward to" address irreversible?

Comment: How did you set it to forward, anyway? If you did it with FBML, you can just append `?v=wall` to get to the wall and do some stuff. Or from the admin section, disable Static FBML or something. I dunno.

Comment: I am curious as well. This does not sound like something you can do through the admin interface. Does not even sound like Facebook would ever allow redirects like that.

Comment: I didn't use any FBML at all... it was just an option in my Facebook fan page settings.  Maybe it's no longer an option, and that's why I can't revert?!

Comment: can you provide a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 2):

When I setup a Facebook campaign I had the Wall redirect to a different tab on the Fan Page. Once the campaign was over, I changed the default landing page to be the wall again. That setting was under Manage Permissions >> Default Landing Tab (pick from a drop down).

I don't know if this helps but might get you looking in the right area.